# Query sum other table field and grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

I  have a query that sum the item sales by day (Grouping)
but i need now to include in this query the recibed sum quantity by day in the same query
but this field is in other table

this is the representation of the two tables

SALES TABLE named "Item_Sales"

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| SaleItemID | SaleItemQty | SaleItemPrice |  SaleItemDate  |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     51026  |       18.00 |         11.31 |     07/01/1016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     14309  |        7.00 |         22.35 |     07/01/2016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     51026  |        6.00 |         11.31 |     07/01/2016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     51026  |       10.00 |         11.31 |     07/02/2016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     14309  |       14.00 |         22.35 |     07/02/2016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
|     14309  |        9.00 |         22.35 |     07/02/2016 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Recibed Items Table named "Items_Rec"

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
| RecItemID | RecItemQty | RecItemPrice |  RecItemDate  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    51026  |      10.00 |        11.31 |    07/01/1016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    14309  |       5.00 |        22.35 |    07/01/2016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    51026  |       5.00 |        11.31 |    07/01/2016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    51026  |      10.00 |        11.31 |    07/02/2016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    14309  |       5.00 |        22.35 |    07/02/2016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
|    14309  |       5.00 |        22.35 |    07/02/2016 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+
```

i have this query but i need to include the RecItemQty SUM From the ITEMS_REC table

```
SELECT
   S.SaleItemID,
   Format(SUM(S.SaleItemQty), "###,##0.00")AS 'Quantity',
   Format(SUM(S.SaleItemPrice), "###,##0.00")AS 'Amount',
   S.SaleItemDate
FROM Items_Sales
GROUP BY S.SaleItemID,S.SaleItemDate
```

And this is the result that i need

```
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
| SaleItemID | SaleItemQty | RecItemQty |SaleItemPrice |  SaleItemDate  |
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     51026  |       24.00 |      15.00 |        11.31 |     07/01/1016 |
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     14309  |        7.00 |       5.00 |        22.35 |     07/01/1016 |
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     51026  |       10.00 |      10.00 |        11.31 |     07/02/1016 |
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     14309  |       23.00 |      10.00 |        22.35 |     07/02/1016 |
+------------+-------------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

THANKS!!

Comment: What is 'Recibed'? Same SaleItemID and dates in both tables? Build two aggregate queries then another query that joins those two on SaleItemID and the two date fields - compound join. Why two tables? Going by the example data, could be 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join the two aggregates on *ItemID* and *ItemDate*. Below uses two derived tables but in MS Access you can save those two aggregate queries as separate stored queries (i.e., views) and join them in another query.

```
SELECT subSales.SaleItemID, subSales.SumSaleItemQty, subRec.SumRecItemQty, 
       subSales.SumSaleItemPrice, subSales.SaleItemDate
FROM

   (SELECT
      S.SaleItemID,
      Format(SUM(S.SaleItemQty), "###,##0.00") AS SumSaleItemQty,
      Format(SUM(S.SaleItemPrice), "###,##0.00") AS SumSaleItemPrice,
      S.SaleItemDate
    FROM Items_Sales S
    GROUP BY S.SaleItemID, S.SaleItemDate) As subSales

INNER JOIN

   (SELECT 
      R.RecItemID,
      Format(SUM(R.RecItemQty), "###,##0.00") AS SumRecItemQty,
      Format(SUM(R.RecItemPrice), "###,##0.00") AS SumRecItemPrice,
      R.RecItemDate
    FROM Items_Rec R
    GROUP BY R.RecItemID, R.RecItemDate) As subRec

ON subSales.SaleItemID = subRec.RecItemID
AND subSales.SaleItemDate = subRec.RecItemDate
```

Also, look into `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` even UNION of the two (for `FULL OUTER`) in case item records are in one table and not the other and you need to still capture all pertinent rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables:

```
SELECT
    S.SaleItemID,
    Format(SUM(R.RecItemQty), "###,##0.00")AS 'Received'
    Format(SUM(S.SaleItemQty), "###,##0.00")AS 'Quantity',
    Format(SUM(S.SaleItemPrice), "###,##0.00")AS 'Amount',
    S.SaleItemDate
 FROM Items_Sales S
 INNER JOIN Items_Rec R
    ON S.SaleItemID = R.RecItemID
    AND S.SalesItemDate = R.RecItemDate
 GROUP BY S.SaleItemID,S.SaleItemDate
```

Comment: Warning: this unit level join may duplicate summations if multiple matched records are in either. You want to join their aggregations. Plus, you do not join on date.